# Why is jquery GET sending only one value in this loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube-api

The function below  is supposed to grab videos for each query and construct some html that depends on `i`

```
function getVideos() {

    var text = "";
    for(var i=0; i<queryArray.length; i++){
        var queryUrl = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q="+queryArray[i]+
              "&max-results=1&orderby=relevance&v=2&alt=json&format=5";

     $.get(queryUrl, function(data){ 
    constructHtml(data, i);
    }, 'json');

    }

}
```

however it is passing `i` as `2` to constructHtml everytime `$.get` is called why's that?
Note: There are two values in `querryArray` and so `"2"` is technically out of bounds.

Comment: The `i` value is not embedded into the construct call when you do the ajax call. JS is pulling up the value of i available at the time constructHTML call is performed, which is sometime AFTER your main for loop is completed, so `i` should almost always be the LAST value set after the loop exits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the default asynchronous nature of `$.get()` your for loop continues executing and your i variable gets reassigned.

The quick way to fix this is to set `async: false` on your `$.get()` this will essentially prevent your for loop from continuing its execution until your `$.get()` has completed meaning your `i` value wont change in the process.

It must be emphasised though that this will prevent all scripts executing on the page until your for loop has finished, potentially locking your users out from completing other actions for an extended period of time.

Comment: setting async to false worked!..perhaps you can reword your response to focus on that specific tip. Thanks!

Comment: Setting `async` to false works, but it's not recommended as it freezes the entire browser while it's waiting for the responses.

Comment: @Guffa That is true and personally i wouldn't recommend it but the alternative would involve stepping a couple levels back and re-evaluating the whole process on the page in order to work out the best way to achieve whats intended.

Comment: @SimonWest: That's not needed, just put a closure in the loop. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Because by the time your callback method is called the `for` loop has finished executing and `i` is set to the highest index in your array + 1.  The value is 2 (even though there are only 2 items) because `i++` gets executed 1 more times than there are items in your array.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function(index) {
    $.get(queryUrl, function(data){ 
    constructHtml(data, index);
    }, 'json');
}(i);
```

The reason your code is not working is because the callback gets executed around the time the loop is done. So you may fire off two or more AJAX operations, but by the time they are done, "i" is now the end of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

This is variable hoisting; variables are always hoisted to function scope, even when you define them within a block.

The inline function you define is 'closing-over' the reference to i, so by the time constructHtml is called, it is the last value. Try defining it as a function at a higher scope, and passing your arguments.

Some reading:

http://oreilly.com/javascript/excerpts/javascript-good-parts/awful-parts.html

Answer (score 0):

That's because the AJAX call is asynchronous, so when the success callback runs the loop has ended, and the value of `i` is what you get when the loop has ended.

Use a closure to preserve the value of `i` for each iteration:

```
function getVideos() {
  var text = "";
  for(var i=0; i<queryArray.length; i++){

    (function(index){

      var queryUrl = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q="+queryArray[index]+
          "&max-results=1&orderby=relevance&v=2&alt=json&format=5";
      $.get(queryUrl, function(data){ 
        constructHtml(data, index);
      }, 'json');

    })(i);

  }
}
```

Here is a demo that uses timers to show that the variable values are retained for asynchronous callbacks: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/WgxPC/

Comment: Thanks for the insight!...this doesn't work though...it still sets i to 2... :(

Comment: @algorithmicCoder: Have you changed the code so that you use the function parameter inside the function, instead of `i`?